# CreateWindow expected an expression and syntax error

Tags: c++, winapi, createwindow

```
#include<windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK window_callback(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

}
    
int WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {
    // Create Window Class
    WNDCLASS window_class = {};
    window_class.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    window_class.lpszClassName = L"Game Window Class";
    window_class.lpfnWndProc = window_callback;

    // Register Class
    RegisterClass(&window_class);


    // Create Window
    CreateWindow(window_class.lpszClassName, "My First Game!", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1280, 720, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
        
}
```

I'm following Dan Zaidan's tutorial on how to make pong in C++, but it is a year or two out of date, which is probably why I'm receiving these errors:

E0029 expected an expression

C2059 syntax error: ')'

There are a few more lines of code, if necessary I can include them.

Edit 1: added 1 CW_USEDEFAULT. I still receive errors, E0167 and C2664.
Edit 2: added more code to hopefully allow you guys to understand better.

Comment: [CreateWindow takes 11 parameters I only count 10 above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-createwindowa) and as this interface has not changed in years (decades) I suspect a typo

Comment: Ok now read [mcve] as we need to see more code and the complete unedited error messages,

Comment: So if you're using `UNICODE` you need to pass Unicode strings to the methods, you can't mix W and A apis, that's undefined behavior.

Comment: *"it is a year or two out of date"* - A year or two mean *nothing* when it comes to C++. A decade or two mean *nothing* when it comes to the Windows API. These things don't change frequently. This is called stability, and it is hard to find.

Answer (score 1):

Getting E0167 and C2664 means you are trying to use ascii strings but your project settings are set to Unicode. You can see in your code when you define the class name string you use the "L" prefix. Do that everywhere. Change `"My First Game!"` to `L"My First Game!"`.